Valgrind fatal error at startup in arch linux
I installed valgrind on my arch system through
sudo pacman -S valgrind

and when attempting to run it, this message appears:
==3821== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3821== Copyright (C) 2002-2024, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3821== Using Valgrind-3.23.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3821== Command: ls
==3821==

valgrind:  Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
valgrind:  which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
valgrind:  cannot be set up.  Details of the redirection are:
valgrind:
valgrind:  A must-be-redirected function
valgrind:  whose name matches the pattern:      strcmp
valgrind:  in an object with soname matching:   ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
valgrind:  was not found whilst processing
valgrind:  symbols from the object with soname: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
valgrind:
valgrind:  Possible fixes: (1, short term): install glibc's debuginfo
valgrind:  package on this machine.  (2, longer term): ask the packagers
valgrind:  for your Linux distribution to please in future ship a non-
valgrind:  stripped ld.so (or whatever the dynamic linker .so is called)
valgrind:  that exports the above-named function using the standard
valgrind:  calling conventions for this platform.  The package you need
valgrind:  to install for fix (1) is called
valgrind:
valgrind:    On Debian, Ubuntu:                 libc6-dbg
valgrind:    On SuSE, openSuSE, Fedora, RHEL:   glibc-debuginfo
valgrind:
valgrind:  Note that if you are debugging a 32 bit process on a
valgrind:  64 bit system, you will need a corresponding 32 bit debuginfo
valgrind:  package (e.g. libc6-dbg:i386).
valgrind:
valgrind:  Cannot continue -- exiting now.  Sorry.

Ive tried rebooting my system and my DEBUGINFOD_URLS looks like this:
❯ echo $DEBUGINFOD_URLS
https://debuginfod.archlinux.org

Also this is the output for pacman -Qi debuginfod
Installed From  : None
Name            : debuginfod
Version         : 0.191-3
Description     : Handle ELF object files and DWARF debugging information (debuginfod)
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://sourceware.org/elfutils/
Licenses        : GPL-3.0-or-later
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : gcc-libs  glibc  libarchive  libarchive.so=13-64  libelf=0.191  libmicrohttpd
                  libmicrohttpd.so=12-64  sqlite  libsqlite3.so=0-64
Optional Deps   : elfutils=0.191: for translations
Required By     : valgrind
Optional For    : binutils
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 339.33 KiB
Packager        : Frederik Schwan <freswa@archlinux.org>
Build Date      : Tue May 7 18:21:08 2024
Install Date    : Thu Jun 27 01:21:43 2024
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature

and for valgrind itself:
Installed From  : extra
Name            : valgrind
Version         : 3.23.0-4
Description     : Tool to help find memory-management problems in programs
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : https://valgrind.org/
Licenses        : GPL-2.0-or-later
Groups          : None
Provides        : valgrind-multilib
Depends On      : glibc  perl  debuginfod
Optional Deps   : lib32-glibc: 32-bit ABI support [installed]
                  python: cg_* scripts [installed]
Required By     : None
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : None
Replaces        : valgrind-multilib
Installed Size  : 67.46 MiB
Packager        : Frederik Schwan <freswa@archlinux.org>
Build Date      : Tue May 7 18:04:05 2024
Install Date    : Thu Jun 27 08:55:25 2024
Install Reason  : Explicitly installed
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature

Ive tried rebooting my system and setting DEBUGINFO_URLS variable

what is the full command line you used ?

@ticktalk "valgrind ls", it's in the log.

Does your ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 have a .debug_info section?

Are you on the lastest version of glibc? I.e. when was your last pacman -Syu?
What do you get when executing debuginfod-find debuginfo <path-to>/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2?
